# A few errors, I cannot figure out why?

Tags: php, mysql

I have no ideea why but i get a few errors in my PHP 
I have tried everything and i simply cannot get it to work,if anyone could help me a bit that would be great

```
Notice: Undefined index: confirmpassword in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\photographer\register\form.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined index: username in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\photographer\register\form.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined index: email in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\photographer\register\form.php on line 9

Notice: Undefined index: password in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\photographer\register\form.php on line 10
```

my code is

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['message'] = '';

    require_once "../db/connect.php";
    if ($_POST['password'] == $_POST['confirmpassword']) {
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        $password = md5($_POST['password']);

        $query = "INSERT INTO finalx VALUES ('$username' '$password' '$email')";

        if (mysqli_query($query) == true) {
            $_SESSION['message'] = 'Inregistrare reusita';
            header("Location: welcome.php");
        }
        else {}
    }
?>
```

Comment: you better add a check ```isset($_POST['confirmpassword'])``` and try to figure out.

Comment: @MoeenBasra all my error dissapeared after doing that , can you please help me understand why the hell?

Comment: I guess your from is not getting submitted properly.

Please make sure you are using the right url to submit the form. If it is right then simply make sure you are not getting the url with get request.

Add a check ```if (!empty($_POST))``` and try again.

Answer (score 0):

a quick and dirty way is to test the post...right after the require_once put this

```
 require_once "../db/connect.php";
 if (count($_POST) == 0)
      die('Need Data to continue');
```

Answer (score 0):

Items you are trying to use from `$_POST` array are simply not defined:

- make sure that data is actually send from your frontend,
- validate the input data before performing any other tasks in the backend, for example with `isset()`.